# Extract a nested list from this JSON object with Python

Tags: python, json

I'm using this python script (*in an attempt*) to extract a nested list from a JSON object.

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

with open('data-science.txt') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

locations = defaultdict(int)

for item in data['included']:
    location = item['attributes']
    print(location)
```

I get the following output:

```
{'name': 'Victoria', 'coord': [51.503378, -0.139134]}
{'name': 'United Kingdom', 'coord': None}
{'name': 'data science'}
{'CEO': None, 'abbreviation': None, 'logoUrl': None, 'title': 'Make IT London'}
{'name': 'Victoria', 'coord': [51.503378, -0.139134]}
{'name': 'United Kingdom', 'coord': None}
{'name': 'data science'}
{'CEO': None, 'abbreviation': None, 'logoUrl': None, 'title': 'Make IT London'}
{'name': 'Victoria', 'coord': [51.503378, -0.139134]}
{'name': 'United Kingdom', 'coord': None}
{'name': 'data science'}
{'CEO': None, 'abbreviation': None, 'logoUrl': None, 'title': 'Make IT London'}
{'name': 'Victoria', 'coord': [51.503378, -0.139134]}
{'name': 'United Kingdom', 'coord': None}
{'name': 'data science'}
{'CEO': None, 'abbreviation': None, 'logoUrl': None, 'title': 'Make IT London'}
{'name': 'Victoria', 'coord': [51.503378, -0.139134]}
{'name': 'United Kingdom', 'coord': None}
{'name': 'data mining'}
{'name': 'data analysis'}
```

But really what I want is the `'coord'` list associated with an `"id"`.

A single record looks like this:

```
    {
        "id": 3,
        "type": "location",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Victoria",
            "coord": [
                51.503378,
                -0.139134
            ]
        }
    },
```

How can I extract the only the `"id": 3` and `"coord": [ 51.503378, -0.139134 ]`?

Comment: I've removed [this link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/s-matthew-english/literate-octo-robot/master/prettyPrint.txt) from the question, as the content within has been deleted. Please try to add examples directly to questions, to avoid external link breakage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little bare-bones but may help.  Baseline - you might want to use the `get` function in python. (See this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

I won't expand too much on the below code - it is fairly simple - but you can add some logic around it to check if id is None or if coord is None and do additional processing for your own purposes.

```
for record in data['included']:
    id = record.get('id', None)
    coord = record.get('attributes', {}).get('coord', None)
```

Comment: how would it be possible to output the `name` too?

Comment: You would use the same pattern - `record.get('attributes', {}).get('name', None)`

Answer (score 2):

You have to access the sub-structure with its key:

```
coords = {}
for item in data['included']:
    coords[item['id']] = item['attributes']['coords']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> data
{'id': 3, 'attributes': {'coord': [51.503378, -0.139134], 'name': 'Victoria'}, 'type': 'location'}
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> my_id = itemgetter('id')
>>> attributes = itemgetter('attributes')
>>> coord = itemgetter('coord')
>>> 
>>> my_id(data), coord(attributes(data))
(3, [51.503378, -0.139134])
>>> {my_id(data) : coord(attributes(data))}
{3: [51.503378, -0.139134]}
>>> d = {}
>>> d[my_id(data)] = coord(attributes(data))
>>> d
{3: [51.503378, -0.139134]}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, the `id` and `type` are always provided through JSON response, and if `type` is `location` then `coord` will be given too:

```
location_map = {}

for item in data.get('included', [])
    if item['type'] == 'location':
        location_map[item['id']] = item['attributes']['coord']

print location_map
```

OR in more pythonic way:

```
location_map = {
    item['id']: item['attributes']['coord']
    for item in data.get('included', []) if item['type'] == 'location'
}
print location_map
```

For sample input:

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "type": "location",
    "attributes": {
        "name": "Victoria",
        "coord": [
            51.503378,
            -0.139134
        ]
     }
  }
]
```

result would be:

```
{3: [51.503378, -0.139134]}
```

For reference see Dict Comprehensions: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

Comment: :/ I don't understand how that would fit in the code.

Comment: I've seen the JSON response `coord` will only be present on the items that are having `type` equals to `'location'`. So, you just have to replace your location with what I've provided (i.e. `location_map`). I don't think there is any rocket science in this. for reference see dict comprehensions: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

Comment: @s.matthew.english did you get it?

Comment: @s.matthew.english, updated my answer with another way of achieving the same outcome.